# MySQL table value be equal with php var (then display it)

Tags: php, html

I have the following MySQL table and I would like to do that RVR11 (500) be equal with a php var $RVR11

I have this code but it doesnt work.

[image: table]

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";


$price = mysql_query("SELECT RVR11 FROM tablename");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($RVR11);
echo $result['RVR11'];
```

Sorry about this beginner question.

Comment: you mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` API what does not work

Answer (score 0):

You should choose a database before any queries, you can pass the fourth arguments to `new mysqli` constructor.